# What permissions does a handle acquired with Process.Handle have?

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to get away from using pinvoke where I can and I came across the following code

```
var processHandle = Process.GetProcessesByName("processName")[0].Handle;
```

I was wondering what [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/process-security-and-access-rights) the handle would have if acquired this way as opposed to calling `OpenProcess` (where you can specify what permissions you want) from the Windows API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the source code, you get

```
NativeMethods.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS;
```

Which is analogous to

> PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
>
> - All possible access rights for a process
>   object.

The chain can be followed as such

- [public static Process[] GetProcessesByName(string processName, string machineName)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system/R/c955a482994fbefb.html)
- [public static Process[] GetProcesses(string machineName)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system/R/87ff4550e7d5526b.html)
- [Process(string machineName, bool isRemoteMachine, int processId, ProcessInfo processInfo)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system/R/856ca606a975ba31.html)